# Como continuar o código após IF

Tags: vb.net

Olá, numa determinada parte do meu programa, preciso procurar algumas palavras-chave em um arquivo de texto. Estou usando o método IF e CONTAINS para isso, porém, quando ele encontra alguma dessas palavras-chave, ele para de procurar as próximas, e eu preciso que ele pesquise até o fim. Meu código:

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader(Path)
    Dim rd As String

    rd = sr.ReadToEnd()

    If rd.Contains("IDCmdpaotj") Then
        Str = "IDCmdpaotj  **(Finded!)"
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Str)
        LabelText.Text = "IDCmdpaotj Found!"
        End if

    If rd.Contains("xxpodDooe") Then
        Str = "xxpodDooe  **(Finded!)"
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Str)
        LabelText.Text = "xxpodDooe Found!"
        End if
```

o problema é que ao encontrar "IDCmdpaotj" , ele simplesmente para e não continua tentando encontrar "xxpodDooe". Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Manda a rotina inteira fazendo um favor Happy.

Comment: Nessa linha `LabelText.Text = "IDCmdpaotj Found!` você não esta fechando a `"`, não seria esse o problema?

Comment: como o amigo @RobertodeCampos passou creio q o primeiro `IF` esteja faltando as `"`.

Comment: Boa tarde, talvez se você utilizar o if dentro de while ou for, resolva seu problema

Comment: Não é isto, eu digitei o código errado na pergunta. O if está fechado no código original.

Comment: FINDED? Vc quis dizer FOUND? Por sinal o label text só terá a última encontrada. Tem certeza de que ele para de procurar? colocou um breakpoint?

Comment: Por este código não consigo imaginar porque pare, não tem um comando que mande parar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido! O código estava dentro de um timer, e o mesmo estava sendo parado por outro. Sem isto, tudo fluiu como esperado. Obrigado pela ajuda!